# Why Push Button is disabled even though disable property is set false?

Tags: mfc

I have many control on dialog box.
I added one push button on dialog box.

When I run my code newly added push button is in default state.

Following things i have done

1. I checked my source file if I have disabled it by code. but I didn't
   disabled by code.
2. I have checked all property of button,disable is off there also.
3. I have replaced the id of newly push button with old push button. push button gets enable.

Comment: the problem is, a lot of users *think* they *know* what their program does, but quite often they are wrong. because of this, we expect you to post minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe you have two controls with the same ID. Check in the resource.h file and make the new button ID have a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Chance that you disabled the button in the resource temaplte?
Launch the test mode of the dialog in the resource editor and check how ist state is set.